# I need to add by Power Virtual agent bot to Microsoft teams left navigation bar for all the users in organization

Tags: power-virtual-agents

I need to add by Power Virtual agent bot to Microsoft teams left navigation bar, so that it is pinned and available to all users in an organization, how can I do this without adding the bot to App-studio? Should I submit for admin approval so that I can add in organization wide global MS-teams policy?
To make the Bot available for other users in searches under "More Apps" section of teams
is it sufficient that the bot is sent to teams admin approval without adding in App Studio?
How to pin the Bot for all organizational users after it is available under more apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the bot available to everyone in the organization and enable installation, the bot should be submitted for Admin approval and approved by an Admin as per [these instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-virtual-agents/teams/publication-add-bot-to-microsoft-teams-teams#submit-for-the-built-by-your-org-section).

A Teams Admin can then proceed to Pin the application for all users or specific users using a policy in the teams admin center [by creating or modifying an app policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/teams-app-setup-policies#create-a-custom-app-setup-policy).